# This insertion sort algorithm only swaps the first 2 elements and stops. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, sorting, nested

Given an array, a start index, and an end index, output the array in sorted order. Example {"c","b","d","a"} --> {"a","b","c","d"}

Problem is that the algo only performs the desired swap between first index and the one before it (if swap conditions are met).

```
    public void insertionSort(String[] array, int start, int how_many_elements) { // ndx start
        for (int i = start + 1; (i < start + 1 + how_many_elements) && (i < data.length - 1); i++) { // assume in bounds
            String key = data[i];
            int j = fi;
            while (j >= 0 && key.compareTo(data[j]) < 0) { // swap
                String temp = data[j];
                data[j] = key;
                data[i] = temp;
                j--; // continue down to first element
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `j` should be `i - 1` each time, instead of the start index.
2. In the loop, just set the value of the next element to the current element. (This must be done once more after the loop.)

```java
public void insertionSort(String[] data, int fi, int how_many_elements) {
    for (int i = fi + 1; (i < fi + 1 + how_many_elements) && (i < data.length); i++) {
        String key = data[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && key.compareTo(data[j]) < 0) {
            data[j + 1] = data[j];
            j--;
        }
        data[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```